# Error When Running BrowserSync from Package.json Scripts

Tags: node.js, express, package.json, browser-sync, npm-scripts

I have set up Browser Sync to work with nodemon and express.  I am **not** using gulp or grunt, but rather running everything through npm scripts in my package.json file.

Now, everything works, but I get an error when running my scripts and would like to know what the error is about and how I can fix it.

First, here is my setup:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "dev:css": "postcss assets/css/style.css -o public/assets/css/style.css",
    "dev:sync": "browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:3000' --files='./views/**/*.html' --no-ui --no-notify",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"npm:dev:css\" \"nodemon app.js -e js,html\" \"npm:dev:sync\"",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.10",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2"
  }
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
 YError: Invalid first argument. Expected boolean or string but received function.
[dev:sync]     at argumentTypeError (C:\laragon\www\projects\startup-reporter--node\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\argsert.js:64:11)
[dev:sync]     at C:\laragon\www\projects\startup-reporter--node\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\argsert.js:45:17
[dev:sync]     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
[dev:sync]     at Object.argsert (C:\laragon\www\projects\startup-reporter--node\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\argsert.js:38:25)
[dev:sync]     at Object.version (C:\laragon\www\projects\startup-reporter--node\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\yargs.js:796:19)
[dev:sync]     at runFromCli (C:\laragon\www\projects\startup-reporter--node\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\bin.js:46:10)
[dev:sync]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\www\projects\startup-reporter--node\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\bin.js:38:5)
[dev:sync]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
[dev:sync]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
[dev:sync]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
```

Any idea what this message is about and how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There was an issue opened in the repo here: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1782

Looks like a downgrade might be a  workaround until the team addresses the issue. `npm -g install browser-sync@2.26.7`. I just confirmed this does remove the warning.

Also noted there that this is not an error, but a warning, so the package will work as expected, but console output will be muddied.

Comment: Downgraded for the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I installed browser-sync, via `sudo npm install -g browser-sync` on my linux machine and i get the exact same error.

Node version:

```
~$ node -v
v10.13.0
```

Npm version:

```
~$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

Then i run `browser-sync --version` to get:

```
YError: Invalid first argument. Expected boolean or string but received function.
    at argumentTypeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/yargs/build/lib/argsert.js:64:11)
    at parsed.optional.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/yargs/build/lib/argsert.js:45:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.argsert (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/yargs/build/lib/argsert.js:38:25)
    at Object.version (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/yargs/build/lib/yargs.js:796:19)
    at runFromCli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync/dist/bin.js:46:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync/dist/bin.js:38:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
[Function]
```

Although i am beginner with npm, it does not seem to be a permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error on windows, I tried as per documentation installing visual studio to fix some c+ problem and reinstalled and it keeps appearing the same error, when I install globally it works'ish but if I install on a single project it does not even recognize browser-sync version prompt, I tried updating npm and node, and the problem remain, but I notice that when I install things like node-sass I'm having the same issue which were not there before, so I'm guessing the problem has to do with some global configuration of npm, I reinstalled it and still nothing, so something else must be conflicting it, today I was gonna try yarn, and see what happens.

what do you get when you prompt npm list --depth 0

https://gist.github.com/soyrbto/5bc81049780baab3f3c4211c0b7548bd

this is happening to me, I want to check that we have the same problem

Comment: I am not getting any errors when running `npm list --depth 0`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I uninstall node from the ground using this
[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)
and reinstalled it (if you want to install additional components as chocolatey you have to have installed visual studio 2017 if not you will see an error)

after I reinstalled it I managed to install and get working the packages again, it seems that it was a conflict that does not disappear unless you remove the folders manually.

Also I install the latest version of node, I dont believe this has nothing to do with it but in case you want replicate exactly what I did.