# browser-sync installed by npm is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, browser-sync

I'm trying to install browser-sync using npm line and I get:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I tried updating node (uninstalled and installed it again) current version is v12.18.2 and npm 6.14.6

only weird thing i did before was running this line npm install -g npm@latest which i did not notice was for mac.

when I call for the version (browser-sync --version) i get

```
YError: Invalid first argument. Expected boolean or string but received function.
    at argumentTypeError (C:\Users\rate9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\argsert.js:64:11)
    at C:\Users\rate9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\argsert.js:45:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.argsert (C:\Users\rate9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\argsert.js:38:25)
    at Object.version (C:\Users\rate9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\yargs.js:796:19)
    at runFromCli (C:\Users\rate9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\bin.js:46:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rate9\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\bin.js:38:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
[Function]
```

I'm running windows 10

thanks!

Comment: Ciao, these are warnings not errors. If you tipe in command prompt `browser-sync -v` what do you see?

Comment: As stated above it is a warning about an optional dependency not supported by your platform. The NPM ecosystem sadly has lots of these warnings making people start ignoring these warnings and thus missing real problems.

Comment: I updated the post and added what I get when I prompt browser-sync --version I already see that this warnings are a big deal around npm but in my case it seems that it crashes the package as it does not work

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@gichuwil/browsersync-on-windows-10-workaround-2173fb1f71a4) post is old but could help.

Comment: @giovanniEsposito thanks for the quick reply and looking up the article, but it seems that the tree folder has changed as it was no browser-sync in my nodejs installation and there where 3 folders in node modules (browser-sync, browser--sync-client, browser-sync-ui) it looks like that fix is outdated

Comment: I tried :) Sorry if I haven't been very helpful.

Comment: Same here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62982935/3483217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to reside in the newest version of `browser-sync`, I rolled back to an older version and seems to be working fine

`npm install -g browser-sync@2.26.7`